# Wordpress shows my picture in admin bar

Tags: images, wp-admin

I have installed wordpress on my dev but during installation, I did not upload any picture for my profile but on admin bar, it is showing my picture. How I can remove it?

Comment: picture is same as on my stackoverflow account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a gravatar. Change your user email to another email that is not registered at gravatar, or change the image to a blank .jpg at https://en.gravatar.com/

Comment: has it right. Also worth noting, you're the only person who will see your picture, and then only when you're logged in. The only place your users might see it is if they have administrator-level WordPress accounts on your site and are able to look at the full 'Users' page where I think the photos also display. But they will not see it in the top admin bar ever.

Comment: yes but client is also seeing my picture

Comment: I think anyone will see the image, as any web site that has a registration with that email will query gravatar.com for the image.

Comment: changed the email address and it worked

Answer (score 1):

> (...) but client is also seeing my picture

<sup>*- OP in a comment*</sup>

If you want to disable it completely, the following should work (wrote a little (MU-)Plugin for you):

```
<?php
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
/* Plugin Name: (#65698) »kaiser« Disable Avatar */
add_filter( 'get_avatar', '__return_null' );
```

Just drop it into your plugins or mu-plugins folder, activate it in your client installations and you disabled the gravatars successfully.

Comment: that's very nice of you @kaiser but I have to change the email address to my official email address and it worked. In future, will definitely use yours